# the selected file is not a valid solution file in microsoft visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am using microsoft visual studio 2012, I double my solution file then get this error, I have tried by opening the file>Open>Project/Solution, then select the file name, but it still could not work and get the error as below:

```
the selected file is not a valid solution file
```

Comment: Looks like the file is corrupt.

Comment: yes, my file is corrupt

Comment: Well then how do you expect it to load successfully?

Answer (score 2):

Try to open your .sln file.
most probably file may contain Null values or empty.
In my case it works after replacing .sln file with early backup .sln file.
Or try to get this file in TFS working version.
because it contain all your solution related data.
eg. VS version, class library details...